# No "autocompletion" support in QtCreator with auto variable

Tags: c++, autocomplete, c++11, qt-creator

I am testing different IDE's and QtCreator was my favorite so far but it seems that there is no support for the auto keyword?

[image]

I am new to c++ but bot variants should be the same right? (Maybe unique pointer)  But I get no autocompletion with the variable `o1`

Did I just make a mistake or has QtCreator no support for auto?

Comment: Yes of course, the code above compiles perfectly. I am using MinGW 4.7.2 and  `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11`

Comment: Even without C++11, `auto` is a valid (albeit useless) keyword.

Comment: I am using 2.6.1 and it seems that the problem here is make_shared, because `auto t = Test(1);` is working. @CharlesSalvia Yes but it has a completely different meaning, and I am not talking here about syntax highlighting, I am talking about autocompletion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is most likely not the auto keyword:-)

Creator still has quite a few problems with templates as the parser is taking shortcuts. There is work in progress to fix that by using the clang parser instead. But since that does not do shortcuts it is *way* slower than the current one, so there is additional work needed to either speed up clang for the IDE use-case, add some kind of caching of the code model to Creator (currently creator does not store any information about it, so there are never any issues with caches being outdated, etc.) or use the current parser first and then refine the code model later with clang.